# Which is the right way to concatenate files and appending "New Line" in Python? Binary mode or Text Mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to concatenate many files in a root to a single file. However I'm stuck on these problems:

- When I've opened each textfile in text file mode the output file shows
  strange characters like japanese characters.
- When I've opened each textfile in binary mode the output file was corrected except that I need to write a "new line" before each text file appended.

I'm using Python3 and my OS is Windows 7.

I've advanced to this following code:

```
import os, shutil

def concatFiles():  
    path = 'D:\\concat\\';
    scriptFullFilename = 'scriptFull.sql'
    if os.path.isfile(path + scriptFullFilename):
        os.remove(scriptFullFilename)   
    files = os.listdir(path);   
    filenames = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.sql')]    
    newLine = "\n"
    with open(path + scriptFullFilename, mode='wb') as outfile:     
        for fname in filenames:
            with open(fname,'rb') as source:                
                shutil.copyfileobj(source, outfile, 1024*1024*10)                           
    print('Done')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    concatFiles();
```

Comment: You’re probably using the wrong encoding for the file. If you write a file in one encoding and read it in a different encoding, you get mojibake—nonsensical characters made up of the same bytes being interpreted in the wrong way.

Comment: Now I figured out, thanks. I'll organize all files in the same encode type. The nonsensical characters got in my way.